# Facebook's new rate limits

Tags: facebook

Starting July 11, 2016 Facebook has released its new page level limits as described in https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2016/06/16/page-level-rate-limits/.

However the documentation does not clarify following points:

1. For which combination of page/user/page access token/application does the page level limit apply exactly? As we know a page access token is related to a user, to a page and to an application. Does the limit apply to all page access tokens fetched with a given user? Does it apply to all page access tokens fetched with a given application and a given user? Or does it apply to some other combination thereof?
2. What happens when the limits are reached and error code #32 is returned? For how long is the page blocked? Documentation states "up to an hour" but platform bug replies state "up to 24 hours"
3. How often are the x-page-usage values updated? We experience the situation that the values do not change for hours although we reduce the frequency of our calls significantly and although we have additional users engaging with the page.

And generally I would like to know if the new rate limits work seamlessly or if there are any known problems with them currently.

Thanks,
Michail

Answer (score 1):

Here are some answers:

1. The page limit belongs to the page, so every app has to share the quota.

   > Starting July 11, 2016, calls made to the Pages API using Page access tokens will be rate limited on the Page level, as opposed to on the app level. This means that each Page has a dedicated quota that is shared across all apps using the Page's access token.
2. It depends on the calls. Because of the sliding window the calls you made can only go down slowly. So you should perhaps stop making any call and try some test call in a well chosen time interval.

   > A Page management app will remain rate limited for as long as its usage in the current 24-hour window exceeds the Page's allowed limit.
3. So this can be found in de documentation:

   > The Page level rate limits will follow a 24-hour sliding window.